# What if I hate hats *and* snowflakes?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I'm not interested in the Winter Bash, so I'd prefer it didn't catch my attention in the top bar.

I can't sensibly hide the snowflake in my custom stylesheet though, because the hats are enabled by default, which means that I *need* the snowflake in order to opt out each year. (If I hide the snowflake, I'll be accosted by hats without warning in a year's time, and may not remember why I can't find a way to do anything about it.)

Once I've opted out for the year, I would like the snowflake to go away.

Can we have that option too?

(It's not exactly a big deal, but it would be nice.)

Comment: Please... Live with it for couple of weeks.

Comment: They can't hide the snowflake just because you hate hats. What if you decide you don't hate hats anymore?

Comment: What if I hate hats, and snowflakes, *and* any additional profile settings?

Comment: @deceze `rm -rf /` is your only hope.

Comment: Cody: Then I would sadly regret having selected the option to not see the snowflake any more, instead of just using the "I hate hats" link, and I would reconsider my hatred of hats the following year. I may even try on and then purchase some hats. Addicted to hat-buying, I ultimately become paralysed by indecision over which hat to wear each day. One day an enormous stack of hat boxes topples over and crushes me. My final thought is that I hate hats. Also snowflakes.

Comment: How can you possibly hate such a special snowflake?

Comment: @phils: Is the mere *existence* of an *icon* bothering you that much that we should have a way to hide it?

Comment: adblocker is great for these kinds of things.

Comment: `sleep(15778800000)`, unless you live in the southern hemisphere, live on Mt. Everest or something like that...

Comment: "Is the mere existence of an icon bothering you that much that we should have a way to hide it?" it's totally bizarre that a programming professional would ask that question, frankly.  Let me make it clear: **"A ridiculous, unfunny, laughable (in the bad sense) advertising icon on SO is so annoying, that, OF COURSE there should, ideally, be a way to disable it in preferences."**

Comment: @JoeBlow: OK, when a "ridiculous, unfunny, laughable (in the bad sense) advertising icon" appears on SO, we can talk about getting rid of it. But at present, a snowflake is none of these things. I fail to understand how a snowflake can be "ridiculous". Snowflakes are neither funny nor unfunny. They're not laughably bad, since again they're not funny. And snowflakes aren't advertising anything. Oh, you might consider *hats* to be all of those. But the snowflake icon *itself* isn't doing any of that. This seems to be an impressive overreaction to something *utterly trivial*.

Comment: a logo is a logo is a logo, marketing is marketing is marketing.  if you're the sort of person that despises logos and marketing, you'll despise it.  If you're saying "at least it's small" - sure.

Comment: you have the means to hide it. hide it.

Comment: @JoeBlow: "*marketing is marketing is marketing*" If there's no product, there is no marketing. And Winterbash isn't a product.

Comment: Actually, the snowflake icon is really nice. Thin lines, discrete, a great example of good UI. Don't be grumpy, I'm sure SO helped you many times, so why not give something back?

Comment: The best compromise would be if the SO team made this feature opt-in like decent human beings rather than opt-out.

Comment: @JoeBlow the two icons to the left of the snowflake aren't logos or marketing.  I suppose you could say they are all advertising the presence of site features.  This feature just happens to be seasonal and entertainment-focused rather than Q&A focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler option for those who have a browser extension that allows blocking scripts on the basis of wildcards. Block scripts from:

```
winterbash*.stackexchange.com
```

This will take care of turning off everything at once, and should work for future years. This year's scripts are downloaded from `winterbash2016.stackexchange.com`. Presumably, next year's scripts will be downloaded from `winterbash2017.stackexchange.com`, etc.

Comment: That's a great idea, but I'm also seeing (at minimum) http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/theactualhats.js in use, so I suspect at minimum that URL prefix should be blocked as well.

Comment: Confirming that setting an AdBlockPlus filter on `winterbash*.stackexchange.com` and `cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/*` does the trick. In fact, at least for this year, blocking the latter alone seems to be sufficient. I would guess that even if the URLs change, this general approach will work in future years.

Comment: I'm surprised you need to block scripts originating from `sstatic.net` too. When the winterbash started this year, I could not see anything. I looked for a setting to turn it on but could not find it. No snowflake, nothing. Then I realized that `winterbash2016.stackexchange.com` was blocked by my script blocker and once I unblocked that, it worked fine.

Comment: Blocking the sstatic.net/WinterBash URLs might not be *necessary*; but that does seem to be where the behaviour originates (such that if you block that, the site doesn't attempt to contact winterbash2016.stackexchange.com at all), so while I've not looked at any of the script contents, blocking the former seems like it might avoid some activity not accounted for by only blocking the latter.

Comment: For reference, the AdBlockPlus filter I'm using is: `||sstatic.net/WinterBash/*`

Answer (score 33):

As you said, you can install a user stylesheet that hides it:

```
.icon-winterbash {
    display: none;
}
```

(just for reference for other users with the same idea).

Whenever you sense that it's Winterbash season again, you can disable it temporarily to opt out. Even better, put an appointment in your calendar dated December 1st, 2017 to remind you to turn the user script off.

Comment: I explained why that approach is problematic in my question.

Comment: @phils I have updated my answer with a possible workaround for you.

Comment: This is not a solution.  It would be polite of SO if they took a minute to make it possible to get rid of seasonal-advertising-crap, in one's preferences.  (SO  generally have a generous policy of making ads and marketing crap as unobtrusive as possible - you can often turn off ads and stuff - so it would be polite of them if they did this as well.)

Comment: @JoeBlow seasonal-*advertising*? I didn't see any ads?

Comment: Yea, and maybe you can get Google or Microsoft to stop tracking your locations.

Comment: @phils Why don't you hide the hats as well then? The class is `.hat`.

Comment: @TheVee That's a good idea. Does that really account for all Winter Bash content, though?? (I don't know what "I hate hats" actually does.)

Comment: @phils I'll do some investigating.

Comment: The Hot Network Questions feature for me was similar.  I didn't care to see it (too distracting when on the clock! :) so I hid it with css.  In my case, I set opacity to 0.001 and a :hover style to set the opacity back to 1.0.  If you do similarly w/ the snowflake you don't have to remember how to get back to it - just where to mouse over to see it.

Answer (score 5):

All the changes seem to be just visual. To have the Winter Bash not affect you in the upcoming years without having to repeat some steps every December, you can hide all the elements it adds to the UI:

1. the snowflake: `.icon-winterbash`
   [image]
2. all the hats displayed over other people's avatars: `.hat`
   [image]
3. the hat count indicator on "Activity" tab: `.wb-activitytab-hat`
   [image]
4. the hat count indicator on "Profile" tab: `#wb-newprofile-snowflake` and `#wb-hat-count`
   [image]

Hat notifications appear separately over the snowflake (within its `<div>`), so 1. also takes care of those.

Of course, with this solution, **you would still receive hats,** because they are awarded for actions you normally do (like asking on Meta) – they should just not disturb your UX in any way.

The only downside I can think of is the marginal possibility of unknowingly receiving some obscure super-rare hat like "collect 15 different hats but never wear any of them" and getting praised as a Stack Overflow hat hero in the January news :-D